# When adding a WebPart I get "List does not exist" error in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I created a list (Promoted Links) and exported the list as a WebPart using SPD and added the list to the gallery.  But whenever I try to add the list to another page or site, I get the

> "List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."

This is an on premise SharePoint environment, but I do not have access to any logs or such.  :(

The GUID of the list according to SPD is: `{772FD3B3-7007-4256-853E-B18608B1997E}`

I can get to the lists properties from: `http://OurServer/siteops/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={772fd3b3-7007-4256-853e-b18608b1997e}`

The list is viewable by all users, including guests, same permissions as the list that works.

I don't think I got the prompt

> "Do you want this Web Part to always show list data from the current
>   web site? ..."

when I exported the WebPart.

Please, any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the webpart:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<webParts>
    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
            <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
            <properties>
                <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="Default" type="string">TRUE</property>
                <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" null="true" />
                <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
                <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
                <property name="ManualRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="ListUrl" type="string">/SiteOps/Lists/PCLI Links<Property/>
                <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">{772fd3b3-7007-4256-853e-b18608b1997e}</property>
                <property name="TitleUrl" type="string">/SiteOps/Lists/PCLI Links</property>
                <property name="WebUrl" type="string">/sites/cerner</property>
                <property name="EnableOriginalValue" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
                <property name="ServerRender" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="ViewFlags" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPViewFlags, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">None</property>
                <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="ListName" type="string">{772FD3B3-7007-4256-853E-B18608B1997E}</property>
                <property name="ListDisplayName" type="string" />
                <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
                <property name="DisableSaveAsNewViewButton" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="ViewFlag" type="string" />
                <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
                <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
                <property name="AutoRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="Description" type="string" />
                <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
                <property name="BaseXsltHashKey" type="string" null="true" />
                <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
                <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">Default</property>
                <property name="Xsl" type="string" null="true" />
                <property name="JSLink" type="string" null="true" />
                <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                <property name="SampleData" type="string" null="true" />
                <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
                <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
                <property name="ShowTimelineIfAvailable" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="Width" type="string" />
                <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
                <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="Title" type="string" />
                <property name="PageType" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.PAGETYPE, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW</property>
                <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
                <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="WebId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</property>
                <property name="Height" type="string" />
                <property name="GhostedXslLink" type="string">main.xsl</property>
                <property name="DisableViewSelectorMenu" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="DisplayName" type="string">Tiles</property>
                <property name="IsClientRender" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="XmlDefinition" type="string">
&lt;View Name="{9DD05662-7526-4018-951E-C077DC25C90E}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" ReadOnly="TRUE" OrderedView="TRUE" DisplayName="Tiles" Url="http://dept.pcli.com/SiteOps/Lists/PCLI Links/Tiles.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" &gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="TileOrder" Ascending="TRUE"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Title"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="BackgroundImageLocation"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="Description"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="LinkLocation"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="LaunchBehavior"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="BackgroundImageClusterX"/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name="BackgroundImageClusterY"/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;RowLimit Paged="TRUE"&gt;30&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;JSLink&gt;sp.ui.tileview.js&lt;/JSLink&gt;&lt;XslLink Default="TRUE"&gt;main.xsl&lt;/XslLink&gt;&lt;Toolbar Type="Standard"/&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</property>
                <property name="InitialAsyncDataFetch" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
                <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string">
  &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" /&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" /&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" /&gt;
            &lt;ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /&gt;&lt;ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" /&gt;&lt;ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" /&gt;</property>
                <property name="DataSourceMode" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceMode, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">List</property>
                <property name="AutoRefreshInterval" type="int">60</property>
                <property name="AsyncRefresh" type="bool">False</property>
                <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
                <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
                <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
                <property name="SelectParameters" type="string" />
            </properties>
        </data>
    </webPart>
</webParts>
```

I upload the webpart to the Site Gallery, and once I add it to a subsite page it gives the error.  I tried adding the webpart from the gallery to the top site, and it works fine.  I have updated the code with revisions (I will correct on Monday in case I couldn't remember it well)  Thank you @kesava.

Comment: Was there a final resolution on this issue? I am facing this same challenge in a SharePoint Online environment, trying to import a web part into one site collection from another.

Comment: Sadly there was no resolution for my case.  However, you should try these suggestions with SP Online, it may give you better results, or ask on the Stack Overflow.  Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

can u add "lists/yourlistname" for the property listurl ( make sure the list is located in the same root sitecollection or with in the subsite based on the location where ever you add) and give a try. Also, GUID property should be with braces.

Comment: Thank you @kesava, I did as you suggested, and now I'm being told (when trying to add the webpart to a page) "The file you imported is not valid.  Verify that the file is a Web Part description file (*.webpart or *.dwp) and that it contains well-formed XML.  Here are the only two lines that I edited:

<property name="ListName" type="string">{772FD3B3-7007-4256-853E-B18608B1997E}</property>

<property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">{772fd3b3-7007-4256-853e-b18608b1997e}</property>

Comment: you should save the exported file as .webpart and then upload the modified one in to web part gallary. that should work. i would suggest you can do with in the browser itself via web part menu.

Comment: I did that, I even deleted the old webpart from the gallery just in case.  It uploads to the gallery fine, but once I try to add the webpart from the gallery to a page it gives me the error.

Comment: My bad @kesava, I changed these two lines <property name="ListUrl" type="string" null="true">/SiteOps/Lists/PCLI Links</property> and <property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">{772fd3b3-7007-4256-853e-b18608b1997e}</property>  Do I need to remove the null="true" from the ListUrl Property?  With just those two changes it's still just telling me the list doesn't exist.

Comment: The list exists on http://SERVER/SiteOps/SitePages/Home.aspx (actually http://SERVER/SiteOps/Lists/PCLI%20Links/Tiles.aspx) and I'm getting the error when adding it to http://SERVER/siteops/albuquerque/SitePages/Home.aspx.  If I add it to the http://SERVER/SiteOps/SitePages/Home.aspx page it works fine.  If that helps.

Comment: pls update the question instead of a comment so this gets better visibility.